# Steps for creating a custom view

Tags: android-widget, android-view, android

How can I create a custom view with a custom style? I have many TextView's in my layout and its kind of difficult to manage all of them. I want to group them in a custom view with custom look (a box with rounded corners) and in my code just give the values to the custom view code to handle it itself.

What I am looking after is something like:

[image]

Can someone plesae tell me the steps to create such custom view with rounded box and few TextView's inside it?

Comment: Use a container layout (Preferable relative layout) and embed your textviews inside? Not so tough eh?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to inherit from View. Either programatically or in designer You assign any layout to this view. To the layout You assign Your elements ( TextViews, whatever ). 
Create methods in the derived View class which fill the inner elements, something like getters/setters, like properties in c#. Those are public.
Then place Your custom compound control onto Your main view.
I for myself created a column orientated tablecontrol with custom scrollbar this way ( but pure via code ) and it works very well. Ah, and additionally You can draw shapes on Your derived view, which allow You relatively simple to apply round corners, and even color transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

- You can create a layout for your view. You need to take different layout widgets like textviews etc. and assign them values.
- You can use canvas to draw such view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using eclipse to create your android project.

Go to your src file and create a new layout (relative layout works best here). There is a visual representation of the layout you're creating so you should be able to play around with it. Drag and drop the textviews where you want them and give them unique names. Then in your java code, call the textviews like:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_name_here);
text.setText("Your Text Here");
```

There are plenty of examples online.